# Nameservers with CloudFlare

Tags: nameserver, cloudflare

I want to make a hosting service but I don't want to expose my IP address.
So, I set my account up at cloudflare and setup the DNS records on cloudflare and set my host up.
But now, I can't seem to get the nameservers up without getting my IP exposed.
The record I have right now is

```
Type          Name         Destination
A             ns1          My public IP
A             ns2          My public IP
A             @            My public IP
CNAME         www          My public IP
```

If I disable cloudflare on my nameservers, the nameservers work fine.
How can I make this work, or is it impossible?

Comment: Learn how DNS works, read the Cloudflare instructions. Hire someon able to understand them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Haha, I feel sorry to see your question got voted down. But I think it is legit question as those DNS stuff is so confusing and it is pain to learn, and even after you understand it, easy to forget.

I have setup server website, like 10, via cloudFlare but still hate doing those configs.

Now, there are 2-3 things you need to do.

1/ Go to cloudflare, setup your new website with a domain ( which you already purchased somewhere). You don't need your website (source code, DB and stuff) up and running at this point. If you do it right ( it is quite easy, just next and next), **their should give your 2 nameservers**

2/ Go to Your domain name provider. Login there, and set your nameserver to external nameservers, then put those 2 nameservers in step 1.

3/ Now, get your hosting ready, then paste the IP into DNS records, which is different than nameservers.

Now your IP should be **quite** private to you and cloudflare only. As most user will only see Cloudflare IP (which is the proxy, load balance for your website)

Hope I won't make you confuse even more. And not sure it is as clear as Cloudflare guide, lol 
https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/205195708-Step-3-Change-your-domain-name-servers-to-Cloudflare

P/S: welcome to the painful world of webmaster, lol. Greetings from someone who have 10+ y of software/web development.

Comment: Thanks! Those other people didn't help so much :P